# We are no longer accepting questions from this account

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, moderators, suspensions

When I try to post a question in software engineering site of SO, it gives me below message and I cannot post any.

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the
>   Help Center to learn more.

[image]

I found the post regarding this kind of [issues here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273741)

[Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273743) suggested,
Some things to consider for your next questions:

1. You have several times that you ask a question and answer it later
   that day. Self-answering is good, but it appears that you just ask a
   question too fast, without searching and researching good enough.
2. Do not delete any of your questions. Deleted questions still count for
   the ban and if there were any answers, they will even count harder
   against you.

Here is my [account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/208831/sazzad-hissain-khan) and so far it seems clean.

[image]
[image]

I have no deleted answers and questions but still I am facing this issue. How can I get rid of this issue. I need some urgent help.

How can I get moderators feedback on my situation? How can I get to know if there are some older deleted questions and answers which might causing this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you don't have any deleted recent questions, you do have 7 deleted questions out of 10 questions asked. Your net score on questions is also negative.

Your questions are:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386672/example-for-nfr-table-for-data-confidentiality (self deleted)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386480/functional-completeness-vs-correctness-vs-appropriateness (closed, deleted, net negative score)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386260/location-of-microservices-for-vod-architecture (self deleted, net negative score)
- [Subclassing a Singleton class](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372196/subclassing-a-singleton-class)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/371756/pubsub-vs-implicit-invocation-architectural-pattern (self deleted)
- [Best practices for database backward compatibility](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370530/best-practices-for-database-backward-compatibility)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359390/algorithm-finding-all-minimal-point-on-kk-sub-grids-from-nn-matrix (moderator deleted due to cross-posting)
- [Merging algorithm for overlapping intervals](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351286/merging-algorithm-for-overlapping-intervals)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308974/given-n-sets-of-integers-how-to-maximize-the-number-of-non-overlapping-sets (self deleted, net negative score)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308442/given-an-array-of-positive-integers-and-another-integer-k-find-number-of-subs (closed, automatically deleted, net negative score)

The advice [here, on Meta Stack Overflow, is applicable to your situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). Unfortunately, there is nothing that anyone can do. The best you can do is try to fix up some of your questions and post answers to other questions to give positive contributions to the community.

Comment: Thanks a lot thomas. I will look into your suggestions

Comment: I have updated one of the auto deleted questions here (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/386480/208831), but I cannot undelete the post. It says, `A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted`. I am requesting moterators action to undelete the post if the modified question worth it. Is it possible? Thanks.