# How to deal with cross-site duplicate closed posts

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

Stackoverflow is not accepting any post from my account due to some low quality auto/self deleted posts with negative net scores. Response of the site is as follows,

> **You have reached your question limit**
>
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

In [one answer,](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8940/208831) a moderator suggested me to improve and re-open my deleted posts. I found [one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308974/given-n-sets-of-integers-how-to-maximize-the-number-of-non-overlapping-sets) of my posts was deleted due to cross-site duplicate. Due to mistakenly cross site posting, I got some negative score before the post was deleted by me. Is there any way to make it improve and request for re-open. I am affright it is not reopenable because cross site has already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135810/given-n-sets-of-integers-how-to-maximize-the-number-of-non-overlapping-sets) with others contribution?

Note that I have gone through the [help center post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) but did not find anything specific about how to deal with deleted posts for cross-site duplicate issues to get rid of the negative scores. Any further knowledge or link will be helpful.

Comment: Hey community, any reason for downvoting? At least put a comment please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Thomas Owens' answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8939/we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account/8940#8940):

> The best you can do is try to fix up **some** of your questions and post answers to other questions to give positive contributions to the community.

(emphasis mine). But some questions are simply not fixable (at least not without exchanging them by a completely different one), deletion is the only viable option. Crossposts belong into that category.

So if you want to lift your question ban, I recommend to ignore about that single question of yours. Better focus on giving answers to others on this site. I am sure as an SO user with more than 16K rep, you will surely have some software engineering knowledge to share.

Comment: Thanks Brown. Needed the info.

Comment: As deleted questions does not contribute anymore to the community, If I update one of my deleted questions by one of my future clean questions, should there be any issue? I can explain the situation in the edit summary section.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan: I have no more information about the "automatic ban" algorithm than you. But I am pretty sure if you are trying to tweak the system, and a mod becomes aware of this, this is not increasing your chance to lift the ban. Better invest your time in writing some good answers or improving other people's questions.